# In SLD, how do I add a string to a label describing a property?

Tags: geoserver, sld

Using Geoserver, is there any way that I can add a predefined string: "No. "
to a property: **postalnumber**?

```
<sld:Label>
<ogc:PropertyName>postalnumber</ogc:PropertyName>
</sld:Label>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The SLD spec includes a [string concatenation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#string-functions) function. Here's an example of how to use it with labels:

```
         <Label>
            <ogc:Function name="Concatenate">
              <ogc:Literal>No. </ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:PropertyName>postalNumber</ogc:PropertyName>
            </ogc:Function>
          </Label>
```

The above was tested on geoserver version 2.1.